# Javascript check if the time is between 8:30am and 6:30pm

Tags: javascript

Ok so what the title says. I am doing this on a server, so I get the server's time using some PHP code. The problem is that it is a time frame without exact round hour values. Should I use nested if else statements?

```
var serverTimestampMillis = <?php print time() * 1000 ?>;
var checkInterval = 1000;

var checkTime = function () {
    serverTimestampMillis += checkInterval;

    var now = new Date(serverTimestampMillis);

    var timeDiv = document.getElementById('timeDiv');

    var messageDiv = document.getElementById('messageDiv');

    timeDiv.innerHTML = now.toString();


    var dayOfWeek = now.getDay(); // 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, ... 6 = Saturday

    var hour = now.getHours(); // 0 = 12am, 1 = 1am, ... 18 = 6pm
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();

    // check if it's Monday to Thursday between 8:30am and 6:30pm
    // this is where I don't know how to check 8:30
    if (dayOfWeek > 0 && dayOfWeek < 5 && hour > 8 && hour < 18) {
        messageDiv.innerHTML = 'Yes, we are open!';
        messageDiv.className='open';            
    }
    else {
        messageDiv.innerHTML = 'Sorry, we\'re closed!';
        messageDiv.className='closed';
    }
};

// check the time every 1000 milliseconds
setInterval(checkTime, checkInterval);
checkTime();
```

thank you in advance, and sorry for being a noob

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just create two dates with the given times, and check if the date is within those dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just nest your statements, like you said (to make it easier to read), and then check the specific edge cases (8:30-9 and 18:00-18:30).

```
if (dayOfWeek > 0 && dayOfWeek < 5) {
    if ((hour > 8 && hour < 18) ||
        (hour == 8 && minutes >= 30) ||
        (hour == 18 && minutes <= 30)) {
         messageDiv.innerHTML = 'Yes, we are open!';
         messageDiv.className='open';  
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be `&&`s where the `||`s are at the moment? Arrgh,  no wait. Should work. What does @adeneo mean with two dates? Love

Comment: You don't want ampersands where the or's are because only one of the 3 conditions can/should be true.

See Amir Popovich's answer below for the state of a date comparison.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. We can do. Love your self as Lord does. %)p Love https://www.liebdich.com

Answer (score 2):

Compare between two dates using a helper function:

```
 function createDateTime(time) {
    var splitted = time.split(':');
    if (splitted.length != 2) return undefined;

    var date = new Date();
    date.setHours(parseInt(splitted[0], 10));
    date.setMinutes(parseInt(splitted[1], 10));
    date.setSeconds(0);
    return date;
}

var startDate = createDateTime("8:30");
var endDate = createDateTime("17:30");
var now = new Date();
var isBetween = startDate <= now && now <= endDate;

console.log(isBetween);
```

[JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/n8of5L4j/)

Comment: Should probably create now with the server time rather than current time - var now = new Date(serverTimestampMillis);

I imagine it'd be better to construct now and then construct start and end with the current day/month/year and only modify the times

Comment: @BethCrane - I don't think you should use the server time in this kind of way. The page could be created at 8:00 and you never know when the js will be executed. If you want to check the servers time, then remove all the js and do it differently.

Comment: I was going off the example code that OP provided - I don't know their reasons for checking server time rather than current time, but I can think of reasonable ones.

Comment: I needed the server's time because if someone would check the page from a different time zone, on the website they would think the shop is open, while it could have closed 2 hours ago. Most of our clients are from my current time zone, but Australia is a big country, someone from elsewhere could check the website and pass the wrong info unintentionally. But thank you for helping, I appreciate it :)